# Replacing fragment 1 with fragment 2 from an action in fragment 3 in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

As the title suggests, is it possible to replace two fragments while in a third one, for example pressing a button in **fragment 3** replaces **fragment 1** with **fragment 2**, while all 3 are **inside a ViewPager**? For simpler understanding, this is what my PagerAdapter looks like:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int numberOfTabs;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numberOfTabs=numberOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                CreateEventFragmentPage1 tab1 = new CreateEventFragmentPage1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                CreateEventFragmentPage2 tab2 = new CreateEventFragmentPage2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                CreateEventFragmentPage3 tab3 = new CreateEventFragmentPage3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return numberOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Any and all advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an adapter `FragmentPagerAdapter` so there is must be an `notifyChanged` method or similar

And i suppose it will works as `notifyDataSetChanged` with Recyclerview

Another reason for this that surrounded fragments of the current are not fully be destroyed

In addition rewrite method `getItem(int position)` to perform logic of reordering your fragments

Also try out to use an `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Comment: The order of the fragments stays the same, meaning that the position of Fragment 3 after pressing the button doesn't change, on the other hand the other two fragment is simply replaced by another, nothing more, nothing less. I am quite sure this problem doesn't exist on stackoverflow therefore I'm also interested in helping the community who might actually be interested in this.

Comment: That's what he is suggesting. Basically add a method on your adapter `buttonPressed` and set a flag there. Then in your `getItem` method do something like `if(!isPressed) tab1 = new CreateEventFragmentPage1(); else tab1 = new CreateEventFragmentPage1AfterButtonPressed();` And then when you need to change your fragments, call `buttonPressed` with a follow-up `notifiDataSetChanged`. One issue you'll have to solve is how to pass the event from fragment1 to the fragment that hosts the ViewPager and its adapter (for example you can send a broadcast).